# How to customize the UIKeyboard in my app?

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

I want to change the Return button to Go button. 
Any suggestions??

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 *yourtextfieldname*.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyGo;
```

Answer (score 2):

UITextField and UITextView both follow the UITextInputTraits protocol, which defines a `returnKeyType` property. Set that to `UIReturnKeyGo` and you're good to, er, go.